# Puedo trabajar con Java EE sin usar JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Mi duda es que si puedo trabajar javaEE sin necesidad de usar JSP, porque por lo que he leido JSP es como una plantilla donde especificas etiquetas html junto con codigo java, tengo entendido hasta aqui que podemos trabajar sin JSP, porque directamente nosotros podemos implementar los servlets en una clase java, tengo entendido que JSP aparecio para hacerle la vida mas facil al programador, pero, mi duda en si es, cuando un servlet va a dar una respuesta, a fuerza necesita JSP para visualizar la respuesta? o no? ya que JSP en si es un documento html pero con codigo java

Comment: No es necesario, JSP es sólo una más de las tecnologías que ofrece JEE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Un JSP en realidad no es más que un servlet: El código de JSP es transformado primero a una clase java que extiende de HttpServlet y luego compilado como cualquier otra clase normal. Por tanto, cuando un servlet (el controlador) delega la generación del HTML (o cualquier otra salida) a un JSP, no hace más que delegar en otro servlet.

Por tanto puedes no usar esa tecnología y crear las respuestas de tu aplicación usando cualquier otra cosa, desde un simple JSON serializer hasta plantillas como Thymeleaf o Freemarker, generadores de documentos PDF... o sencillamente, desde el mismo servlet, generar un String o un array de bytes y enviarlo en la respuesta.